# Member function definition outside the class

Tags: c++, function, class, header

Firstly, I am giving the codes. Then I am explaining the problem I am facing.

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "acc.h"

using namespace std;
class mem;
int main()
{
    show();
    return 0;
}
```

*acc.h*

```
#ifndef ACC_H
#define ACC_H

#include "acc.cpp"
void show();

class mem{
    int a;
public:
    void showa();
    void seta(int A);
};
#endif
```

*acc.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void mem::showa(){cout<<a<<endl;}
void mem::seta(int A){a = A;}

void show()
{
    mem m;
    m.seta(22);
    string ss;
    cin>>ss;
    cout<<"MY name is "<<ss<<" ";
    m.showa();
}
```

"mem" class I declared in "acc.h" file already and added that "acc.h" into acc.cpp file also. But when I am calling that class from a function. It can't response. Showing "a" and "mem" not declared. How can I perfectly link that class definition and member functions of that class so that calling member functions of that class from another function can't create any problem?

Comment: Why are you placing #include "acc.cpp" in acc.h? I don't think its necessary.

Comment: yep, you are right. I just tried "trial and error" method that's why it was there. I am correcting it. Thanks.

Comment: С++ is well documented language there is no need for “trial and error”

Comment: `acc.cpp` should `#include 'acc.h'` also

Comment: Trial and error is not a good learning method, you should start with [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `#include "acc.cpp"` from the `acc.h` file it should compile without any errors. I tried and it compiles for me. I am using Visual Studio 2010 for the same.

Other than this, few more comments:

1. You can use `#pragma once` in you header file instead of `#ifndef/#define` macros. The former is more cleaner.
2. You dont need to forward declare `class mem` before `main()` as you are already including `acc.h`.
3. the `show()` can be moved to where `main()` is defined making the `acc.h/acc.cpp`files dedicated for the `mem` class.
4. A header file should always be named after the class it is holding i.e. `mem.h/mem.cpp` in your case. This informs which file contains which class even without opening the file.

Comment: unfortunately, your first solution isn't working in Codeblocks 17.01 version IDE.